# 301 Redirecting the domain if the page doesn't contain query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I only want to redirect the root page from 1 subdomain domain to another e.g:
from https://checkout.example.com to https://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/

however, all other pages and query strings with $ and & should remain untouched. e.g:
https://checkout.example.com/?Amount=1899&Invoice=55498213
should remain as it is

I tried multiple htaccess rules texts: Redirect 301, Redirect, RedirectMatch, RewriteRule. All the rules are redirecting the domain with the query strings.

Here is my current .htaccess rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^checkout\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @anubhava This is my current .htaccess rules

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.example\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: @anubhava added

Comment: @anubhava yes, it gives me 500 - internal server error

Comment: @anubhava the current .htaccess is redirecting all the links to `https://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/` I do not want the links with querystring to be redirected.

Comment: @anubhava somehow it is working now, I removed the `RewriteRule ^$` from 2nd line. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I removed the `RewriteRule ^$` from 2nd line" - That alone should have resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error! (Unless perhaps you are on a LiteSpeed server, not Apache?)

Comment: @MrWhite I have activated Ultrafast PHP config on my siteground.com hosting, not sure how it conflicts with that .htaccess rule

Comment: @MrWhite do you know how can I add another exception to the above .htaccess to not redirecting this link? checkout.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally works, Added to the top of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^checkout\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @AmitVerma posted similar answer and that should have worked too

Comment: @anubhava, I need your help again. how can I add an exception to the above .htaccess to not redirect this link? https://checkout.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Replace `^(.*)$` in above `RewriteRule` code with `!^wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^checkout\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.domain2.com/checkout [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` can be removed with `RewriteRule ^$`

Comment: @anubhava I just try it but didn't work